# Not able to access current email details, in Gmail-Addon

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a Gmail Addon and need to access attachments associated with an email, in the addon. However, I get the following error, when testing the addon :

`Exception: Access denied: : Access token does not grant access to the requested thread: msg-f:1709866191276978905`.

I have set the following scopes in oauth:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
```

And this is the code snippet:

```
function startApp(e) {
    return getDocsUI(e);
}

function getDocsUI(e){
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(e.messageMetadata.accessToken);
  let currentEmail = GmailApp.getThreadById(e.messageMetadata.messageId);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().append(`<div>'Accessing docs'</div>`);
}
```

I have already tried other variants of this question, that were present on stack-overflow. Please do let me know what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two things

1. `eventObject.messageMetadata.accessToken` is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects), in the future you should use [eventObject.gmail.accessToken](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail_event_object) instead. Same goes for  `eventObject.gmail.messageId` instead of  `eventObject.messageMetadata.messageId`.
2. `message` and `thread` are not the same thing. For retrieving a message you should use the method [`GmailApp.getMessageById(eventObject.gmail.messageId)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagebyidid) instead of [`getThreadById(eventObject.gmail.messageId)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getthreadbyidid).

Comment: I updated my code to use your suggestions. Now I am getting 'Content not available for this message'.

Comment: It worked, only for email it showed that message.